# Increase MaxLocksPerFile error when modifying a large number of records using VBA in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, registry

I have a VBA script which loops over a MS Access recordset containing over 500k records and makes modifications to every record. When I run this code, I receive the following error message: 
"Run time error 3052: File sharing lock count exceeded. IncreaseMaxLocksPerFile registry entry".

I have read similar questions online, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26542653/run-time-error-3052-file-sharing-lock-count-exceeded-increase-maxlocksperfil), which indicate that I need to modify a registry key (I have actually successfully solved this problem on a Windows 7 machine), but all answers that I have read refer to registry keys that don't exist in Windows 10.

Can anyone point me to the relevant registry key in W10?

Comment: Registry's are not dependent on what version of Windows you are running (i.g. 7 or 10), however there will be a difference in the folder structure between 32-bit and 64-bit variants. There will be a different folder name dependant on the version of Access that you are using. You can see examples of these [here](http://www.anysitesupport.com/access-maxlocksperfile-file-sharing-lock-count-exceeded/). Note the addition of '\Wow6432Node\' for 64-bit OS', and folders for the different office versions (12.0, 14.0).

Comment: Looping through a 500k recordset (with dbOpenDynaset I guess) is not a good idea. Different solutions possible (e.g.: use dbSnapShot and Update Records with SQL), show us your code.